# Angular get nested element using directive on parent

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Here is the code that I have

```
<parent my-directive [toHide]="childRef">

 <child bottom right #childRef>
    <button>Some text </button>
 </child >

</parent >
```

Here I have `my-directive` on the parent element and I want to access the child and apply some style to it.

So in my directive, I have the following.

```
export class MyDirective {
  @Input("toHide") localRef;

  constructor(public element:ElementRef,public renderer:Renderer) {
    console.log('Hello MyDirective Directive');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("All Transtition set");
    console.log(this.localRef);
this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.localRef, 'webkitTransition', 'transform 500ms,top 500ms');
  }
```

As you can see that I am using `this.renderer` to set the style on the element but I get the following.

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: el.style is undefined`

Any help in this regard is appritiated.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(this.localRef);`? I suspect it's `child` directive instance

Comment: are you applying style to nativeElement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `<child>` is a plain HTML element (no component) then this should work (added `nativeElement`)

```ts
this.renderer.setElementStyle(
    this.localRef.nativeElement, 'webkitTransition', 'transform 500ms,top 500ms');
```

if `<child>` is an Angular component change this line

```ts
@Input("toHide") localRef;
```

to

```ts
@ContentChild('childRef', { read: ElementRef }) localRef;
```

and remove [toHide]="childRef"

If an element with a template variable 
is a plain HTML element, reading the reference returns an `ElementRef` and the actual element can be accessed using the `nativeElement` property.

If it is a component or hosts a directive, reading the reference returns the component or directive instance which can't be used to access the DOM element.

`@ViewChild(ren)` and `@ContentChild(ren)` allow to specify what to return from the template variable reference using the `read` parameter, but accessing the template variable reference from within the template doesn't provide that.

However I'd suggest using

```ts
@HostBinding('class.is-transition')
isTransition:boolean false;
```

in the directive and use CSS like

```ts
parent[host-directive] > child {
  -webkit-transition: transform 500ms,top 500ms;
}
```

to apply the styles.

Comment: How does getting an element with ContentChild differ from this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName ? Does it make performance imporve?

Comment: No, you can do that as well. It's just incompatible with SSR and web worker functionality.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template/35209681#35209681 has more details. Besides that I don't know any specific source. http://angular.io might provide something but I don't know specifics