# Using @ViewChild { read: ElementRef } of component causes unit test to fail

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

In my component I have a child component that looks like this:

```
<child-component #childComponent></childComponent>
```

In my parent component I then access this child component using @ViewChild and the `read` parameter to get the ElementRef, and not the component reference. I need the ElementRef to ensure I can get some properties from `nativeElement` that I need. So it's like this:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild('childComponent', { read: ElementRef }) public childComponent: ElementRef;
  public position: string;

  // some way down the code
  private someMethod() {
    if (this.childComponent.nativeElement.offsetLeft > 500) {
      this.position = 'left';
    } else {
      this.position = 'right';
    }
  }
}
```

So this works for the application, however I am writing the tests and mocking the child component, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: ''
})
class ChildComponentMockComponent {
  private nativeElement = {
    get offsetLeft() {
      return 600
    }
  };
}

beforeEach(async(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ ... ],
  declarations: [ ParentComponent, ChildComponentMockComponent ],
  providers: [ ... ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
}).compileComponents()));

it('should have the correct position, based on position of child-component', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'someMethod');
  expect(component.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.position).toBe('left');
});
```

So the test will compile the component, and use the mocked child component values as the proper value and compute the value of `this.position`, which is then asserted in the test.

However, when the `{ read: ElementRef }` parameter is set, the mock gets completely ignored by the TestBed, even though it's being added in the declarations array. If I remove `{ read: ElementRef }`, the mock is used in the test and it passes. But then my application doesn't work, as it is now getting the component reference, where the `nativeElement` property doesn't exist, rather than the element reference.

So how do I get the ElementRef in my application and then in my test use the mock component?

Comment: can you add the test case which you wrote so i can help you to fix it

Comment: Hi @Aravind, the property isn't actually used in the test, sorry for being ambiguous. But the test compiles the component using the mocked child-component instead of the proper one, then in the application code for the component, it uses the value I have set in the mock instead of anything else. The app code sets a variable (true/false) based on the position of the child component, which I then assert in the test. It's quite confusing, but I've added a little more detail to my original post.

Comment: when you use read elementRef, it's not using component instance, so why do you declare the `nativeElement` property on the component instance? do you want to mock `elementRef`?

Comment: `nativeElement` isn't available on the component instance. Ideally yes I'd mock elementRef but I tried to do that and it didn't appear to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this by changing the architecture of the app. The child component now finds it's own offsetLeft property, and then puts it into an output EventEmitter to be picked up the parent component.

```
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Output() offsetPosition: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.offsetPosition.emit(this.el.nativeElement.offsetLeft);
  }
}

export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  public childComponentOffset: number;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // this.childComponentOffset is available
      // needs to be in setTimeout to prevent ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
      // more info: https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4
    }
  }

  public getChildComponentOffset(position: number): void {
    this.childComponentOffset = position;
  }
}
```

And then in the HTML, you just define the child component with output variable and method:

```
<child-component (offsetPosition)="getChildComponentOffset($event)"></child-component>
```

In the test, I then mock ElementRef for the child component and use it as a provider.

```
const mockElementRef: any = {
  get offsetLeft() {
    return position;
  }
};

beforeEach(async(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ ... ],
  declarations: [ ParentComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ElementRef, useValue: mockElementRef }
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
}).compileComponents()));

it('should have the correct position, based on position of child-component', (done) => {
  component.getChildComponentOffset(600);
  setTimeout(() => expect(component.position).toBe('left'));
  done();
});
```